# the nested while loop do not work, instead it displays unexpected '}'

Tags: php, mysql, apache, browser

I used a nested while loop for retrieving data from 2 different tables in sql using php but the browser only displays unexpected '}'.
I also tried setting the nested while loop as comment, it executes in the browser fine.
I checked every "}" , ";" ," " ", and "'", because I think it could be the problem, but I don't see anything wrong with the code.
Can you help me please. Thank you.

```
    <?php
    include '../connect.php';

    $SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribers ORDER BY Name");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($SQL))
{
 ?>
<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">

        <textarea id="header">SARIAYA CABLE NETWORK</textarea>

        <div id="identity">

            <textarea id="address">Name: <?php echo $row['Name']; 
            $name = $row['Name']; ?>

Street: <?php echo $row['Street']; ?>

Brgy/Sitio/Subd: <?php echo $row['Brgy/Sitio/Subd']; ?>

</textarea>

            <div id="logo">

              <div id="logoctr">
                <a href="javascript:;" id="change-logo" title="Change logo">Change Logo</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" id="save-logo" title="Save changes">Save</a>
                |
                <a href="javascript:;" id="delete-logo" title="Delete logo">Delete Logo</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel-logo" title="Cancel changes">Cancel</a>
              </div>

              <div id="logohelp">
                <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br />
                (max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
              </div>
              <img id="image" src="images\logo.png" alt="logo" style="height:7vw; width:7vw;" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div id="customer">

            <textarea id="customer-title">Billing as of <?php echo date('F Y'); ?></textarea>

            <table id="meta">
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Account #</td>
                    <td><textarea><?php echo $row['Account_No.']; ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="meta-head">Date of Billing</td>
                    <td><textarea id="date"><?php echo date('F d Y'); ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Amount Due</td>
                    <td><div class="due"></div></td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

        <table id="items">

          <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Monthly</th>
              <th>Installation</th>
              <th>Transfer</th>
              <th>Reconnection</th>
              <th>Extension</th>
              <th>Misc. fee</th>
          </tr>
<?
$SQLBill=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM billing WHERE Name='$name'");

while($subrow=mysql_fetch_array($SQLBill)){
 ?>       
          <tr class="item-row">
              <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea> <?php echo $subrow['Date']; ?></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
              <td class="description"><textarea> <?php echo $subrow['Monthly']; ?></textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="cost"><?php echo $subrow['Installation']; ?></textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="qty"><?php echo $subrow['Reconnection']; ?></textarea></td>
              <td><span class="price"><?php echo $subrow['Transfer']; ?></span></td>
              <td><?php echo $subrow['Extension']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $subrow['Misc']; ?></td>
          </tr>

          <tr id="hiderow">
            <td colspan="7"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="3" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

              <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="3" class="total-line">Total</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="total"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="3" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

              <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="3" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
              <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due"></div></td>
          </tr>

        </table>

        <div id="terms">
          <h5>Terms</h5>
          <textarea>NET 30 Days. Cutting of service will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</textarea>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
<?php
    }//open of second php
}//close of while


    mysql_close($local);
    mysql_close($network);



    ?>
```

Comment: I think in PHP
 there is no need of semicolon after } so remove it.

Comment: I already tried it earlier, but still no luck. Thank you for the info though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<? // add here like <?php
$SQLBill=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM billing WHERE Name='$name'");

while($subrow=mysql_fetch_array($SQLBill)){
 ?>
```

Here you can add **php** in opening.

Remove the semicolons after } at closing loops

```
</table>

    <div id="terms">
      <h5>Terms</h5>
      <textarea>NET 30 Days. Cutting of service will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</textarea>
    </div>

</div>
```

This code part should be after the end of first while loop. And

```
</body>should be at the end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolons after `}`.

```
<?php
    } //open of second php
} //close of while
```

Comment: @FonsiLuna: and what if you replace `<?` for `<?php` before 2nd SQL query?